# Change to 4 columns from 2

Tags: python, matplotlib, multiple-columns, subplot

I have a function that plots a boxplot and a histogram side by side in two columns. I would like to change my code to make it 4 columns to shorten the output. I have played with the code and I am missing something. I can change it to 4 columns, but then the right 2 are blank and everything is in the two left columns.

I have tried changing the line to

```
ax_box, ax_hist, ax_box2, ax_hist2 = axs[i*ncols], axs[i*ncols+1], axs[i*ncols+2], axs[i*ncols+3]
```

instead of

```
ax_box, ax_hist = axs[i*ncols], axs[i*ncols+1]
```

among other iterations of changing the indexes on the columns.
I am new to python and I know I am missing something that will be obvious to more experienced people.

my code is:

```
`def hist_box_all1(data, bins):
    ncols = 2 # Number of columns for subplots
    nrows = len(data.columns)  # Number of rows for subplots
    height_ratios = [0.75, 0.75] * (nrows // 2) + [0.75] * (nrows % 2)
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=nrows, ncols=ncols, figsize=(15,4*nrows), gridspec_kw={'height_ratios': height_ratios})
    axs = axs.ravel()  # Flatten the array of axes

    for i, feature in enumerate(data.columns):
        ax_box, ax_hist = axs[i*ncols], axs[i*ncols+1]
        sns.set(font_scale=1)  # Set the size of the label
        x = data[feature]
        n = data[feature].mean()  # Get the mean for the legend
        m=data[feature].median()
        sns.boxplot(
            x=x,
            ax=ax_box,
            showmeans=True,
            meanprops={
            "marker": "o",
            "markerfacecolor": "white",
            "markeredgecolor": "black",
            "markersize": "7",
            },
            color="teal",
        )
        sns.histplot(
            x=x,
            bins=bins,
            kde=True,
            stat="density",
            ax=ax_hist,
            color="darkorchid",
            edgecolor="black",
        )

        ax_hist.axvline(
            data[feature].mean(), color="teal", label="mean=%f" % n
        )  # Draw the mean line
        ax_hist.axvline(
            data[feature].median(), color="red", label="median=%f" % m
        ) #Draw the median line
        ax_box.set(yticks=[])  # Format the y axis label
        #sns.despine(ax=ax_hist)  # Remove the axis lines on the hist plot
        #sns.despine(ax=ax_box, left=True)  # Remove the axis lines on the box plot
        ax_hist.legend(loc="upper right")  # Place the legend in the upper right corner
        plt.suptitle(feature)
        plt.tight_layout()`
```

[Here is a screen shot of the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRpdg.png)

[Here is a screen shot of the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osbhk.png)

Answer (score 0):

I find this way of using `matplotlib.pyplot` and `add_subplot()` more convenient to add **multiple subplots in a plot**.

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    fig = plt.figure(figsize=[22, 6])
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 1)  # (1,2) means 1 row 2 columns, '1' at the final index indicates the order of this subplot i.e., first subplot on left side 
    ax.hist(somedata_for_left_side)
    ax.set_title('Title 01')

    ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 2)  # '2' at the final index indicates the order of this subplot i.e., second subplot on the right side 
    ax.hist(somedata_for_right_side)
    ax.set_title('Title 02')
```

Example output plot (different titles and plot type):
[image: Output Plot1]

You can try to adapt this to your code. Let me know if this helps.

Since it's a bit hard to see visually what your error is. Can you add some screenshots for easier understanding?

Comment: I added the image. i should have done that in the beginning. I appreciate your response!

Comment: I should also mention that there are 41 different plots, which is the reason I want to double up the columns.

Comment: Can you show what the `data` looks like? Incorrect `data` format might have affected this line `for i, feature in enumerate(data.columns)`

Comment: I added it, There are 50,000 rows and 41 columns, with the 41st column being 1 for failed and 0 for did not fail.

Comment: The code above does not have the alterations I made for ncols=4 and the other line:ax_box, ax_hist, ax_box2, ax_hist2 = axs[i*ncols], axs[i*ncols+1], axs[i*ncols+2], axs[i*ncols+3]

Comment: I'm honestly not confident about what happened in `ax_box, ax_hist = axs[i*ncols], axs[i*ncols+1]` where the code adds plots into the output image. You should test and make sure it behaves exactly the way you want by trying with small mock `data`.

Comment: OR try my way of adding subplots specified by my answer (`ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 1)`), I have clear control of my plot regarding the number of columns and rows in the output. You can make the third index a variable so that you can let the code knows which position it should place the subplot.

Comment: OK. I was hoping that I had missed something in the syntax or the logic that is causing the issue, a simple fix. I will have to either leave it long or rewrite and adapt.